# Mongodb database on server rather than on local

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to create database for website on mongodb but as per my info database is created on local computer rather than on server. So can you help how to create database on server so that all of my partners can access it .

Comment: Update [mongodb connection string](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following link

[link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/)

Its may be you are not in your server command promt lets check